# Anyone used a WCF client with SSRS a web service?

Tags: c#, wcf, reporting-services

I'm having issues using the WcfTestClient with a SSRS report asmx service.  Has anyone gotten it to work?

---

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory factory)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ReportingService2005Soap.ListSubscriptions(ListSubscriptionsRequest request)
   at ReportingService2005SoapClient.ReportingService2005Soap.ListSubscriptions(ListSubscriptionsRequest request)
```

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out, with the help of another post, which I can't find now.

I used the svcutil utility to create the service/data contracts and provide a client.  Then set the binding as follows.

```
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="SsrsSoapBinding" >
         <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
         </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Eight years later, it's as fresh as the day it was born  :-)